# Identify Dragonlance book featuring gnomes

Tags: story-identification, dragonlance

I am trying to find a particular Dragonlance book that I saw when I was a kid. I remember it being a large volume, possibly multiple books bound as one. I think that the cover had a white border.

In particular, I remember one section relating a visit to a city of gnomes. The book notes that in gnomish culture it is not considered impolite to interrupt someone when speaking because a gnome will prattle on forever if given the chance. I don't remember anything else.

Comment: quite a few Dragonlance books reference gnomes, is there anything more about this particular book?

Comment: I don't really remember much more. I this remark about gnomes occurs the first time a group of adventurers visits a gnomish city. I hope that the remark, though somewhat obscure, is unique enough to identify the book.

Comment: Honestly, from my memory of the series, that may well be from the beginning of the series (Chronicles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several *Dragonlance* books make reference to gnomes, but the first one that came to mind here was [*The Siege of Mt. Nevermind*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BUWLBZA), part of the *Chaos War* series. It's almost entirely set in Mt. Nevermind, the gnome city, and it's one of the few books where different gnomes get different personalities.

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, *Chaos War* was never released as an omnibus edition. The only multi-volume sets I know of are:

- The collector's edition of the [original *Chronicles* trilogy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140115404)
- The collector's edition of the [*Legends* trilogy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140126988).
- The [*War of Souls*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786957158) omnibus

It's been a while since I read any of these, though I can go dig them out if any of them sound familiar. Tasselhoff Burrfoit has a magical time travel device during *Chaos War* and *War of Souls* that sounds decidedly gnomish, so it would make sense for him to visit Mt. Nevermind during one of those series.

Comment: It is from the original tetralogy. In fact, the passage I am remembering is from *Dragons of the Winter Night*, which I was able to confirm by looking through it on Amazon. Many thanks.

Comment: Gotta love little Bupu! Raistlin sure did.

Answer (score -1):

There was a large edition of Chronicles that was 3 books in one with a white cover

It's likely what you're looking for. If not it'll be a good place to start and, is one of my all time favorite series

Comment: This doesn’t explain why it might be the answer. More details explaining why it matches the description would help.